# Определение значений при resize и выполнение функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некий блок, например, меню или табы внутри страницы. Необходимо при прокрутке страницы, чтоб данный блок закрепился на экране, а при подъеме, вернулся на свое место. Ниже есть наполовину готовый пример из которого понятен принцип.

```js
var navOffset = $('.shop-tabs').offset();
var navHeight = $('.shop-tabs').height();
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > navOffset.top) {
        $('.shop-tabs').addClass('fixed');
        $('.shop-tabs-container').css('padding-top', navHeight);
    } else {
        $('.shop-tabs').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.shop-tabs-container').css('padding-top', '0');
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block1,
.block3 {
  height: 1000px;
  background: #eee;
}

.shop-tabs {
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
}

.shop-tabs.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="shop-tabs-container">
  <div class="shop-tabs"></div>
</div>
<div class="block3"></div>
```

Используя `.offset` мы определяем текущее положение блока и когда значение `.scrollTop()` его превышает, фиксируем данный блок. При возврате возвращаем не место.

В чем суть вопроса. Необходимо сделать так, чтоб при масштабировании страницы или сужении экрана вылавливать новые значения высоты `.shop-tabs` и его положения на странице от верхней части экрана, после чего передавать эти значения в условие, которое работает при `resize` и `scroll`. Так же, не выполнять функцию при разрешении менее 980px.

Заранее спасибо